# Why is Geoserver downsampling my geotiff?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I created a KML file from a geotiff using Geoserver, but the image looks really pixelated in Google Earth. The image is a geotiff and is only around 7MB. Any reason why it might look so pixelated?

Comment: which version of Geoserver are you using?

Comment: I am using Geoserver version 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Please do inner tile and add overviews to your tiff file, see here:
http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gs_steroids_sgiannec_foss4g2011.pdf

Comment: I added tiling and overviews as you suggested, but the image still appears the same. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found this on a [mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Unable-to-publish-GeoTiff-images-on-GeoServer-td4558056.html) and I think it is should address your situation as well:

> If you have .tif and .tfw files then you probably do not have geotiff,
>   just a plain tiff with world file for georeferencing. Problem is that
>   world file does not tell the projection.  You can try two options:
>
> - Convert image to GeoTIFF with gdal_translate. Command to use could be like  gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -co tiled=yes
>     test.tiff georeferenced.tif
> - Or create a .prj file which contains the information about the projection in the ESRI style and place it to the same place as .tiff
>     and .tfw

You might want to convert it to a real GeoTIFF as suggested in the list and see if it works.

As for the pixelated images, you can try tweaking the WMS [Raster Rendering options](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/services/WMS.html).

[image]

Try using the bilinear or bicubic interpolation. It should be able to address your pixelation issues.